# C++ cin data limit?

Tags: c++, input, limit, cin, cout

So I took a C++ class in High School, but haven't done it in years, so I'm basically new. So I am wondering if there is a limit to the amount of cins you can do. It allows me to input 7 and then skips all the other inputs to go to the end. My guess is that there's a data limit. Is this correct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int time1;
int time2;
int time3;
int time4;
int time5;
int time6;
int time7;
int time8;
int time9;
int time10;

cout<<"enter number";
cin>>time1;
cout<<"enter number";
cin>>time2;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time3;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time4;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time5;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time6;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time7;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time8;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time9;
cout<<"enter number 1";
cin>>time10;
cout<<"the end?";
}
```

Comment: What have you been inputting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your question. Maybe you inputted something that is not a number and `cin` skipped all the other calls because of `cin.fail()`?

Comment: A limit to the number of `cin <<` you can do would be very strange (especially a limit as low as seven). Something else is going on, but theres not enough information to say what that is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cins unlimited and you need to use loops. Here I provided example of fillind array buy cin.

```
    #include <iosteam>
        using namespace std;
        int main(){
           cout<<"Enter number of cins\n";
           int n;
        cin>>n;
        int a[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
cout<<"Enter "<<i<<" number\n";
        cin>>a[i];
}
         
        }
```

Comment: Asker's code should run fine without _needing_ to use loops, so while they might be sensible it doesn't address the question. Your own code has the problem that it uses a [variable-length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) which isn't part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine if you *only* enter numbers. There is no limit to the amount of `cin`s you can do. My guess is that you enter something that isn't a number, e.g. a string. When that happens `cin`'s error flag is set and future attempts to get input will fail.

What you can do is add some input validation if you want. A simple if statement will do:

```
int num{0};
if (cin >> num)
{
    ....
}
```

If the input is not valid, i.e. the if condition is false, you need to clear the error:

```
cin.clear();
```

and discard everything remaining in the input buffer and newline:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

You could use a `std::vector` to store the numbers instead of separate integer variables and use a do...while loop. Putting this all together your code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> nums;
    int n{0};

    std::cout << "Enter total number to input" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    int i{0};

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter number " << i+1 << std::endl;

        int num{0};
        if (std::cin >> num)
        {
            nums.push_back(num);
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
        }
    } while (i < n);
}
```

Note that I'm not `using namespace std` in my code. That's considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).